# Changing Bootstrap admin template

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I change this Bootstrap 3 admin template

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/dashboard/

like this?

It's easy to remove the top fixed navbar and move everything up of 50px (defined inside `dashboard.css`). What I find difficult, is to modify the sidebar with a top rectangular section for the logo.

[image]

Comment: Would've been nice to have the code of the page rather than the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a top `ul` with these css

```
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
background-color: aquamarine;
```

The second `ul` should have a `margin-top: 30px;`.

Finally update `.sidebar` and add a `top: 0;` to it.

Put your text inside an li, inside the ul you just created.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/w4k50nbo

Comment: Done but there is still a padding on the left-bottom side of the aquamarine rectangle. Added this <ul> `<ul style="top: 0; position: absolute; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%; background-color: aquamarine;">Export</ul>`, `margin-top: 30px` to the second <ul> and  `style="top: 0"` to the sidebar <div>.

Comment: You should add an li inside the ul and then your text inside that li. Didn't mention it, thought it was obvious, answer edited.

Comment: Better but not like yours yet. I would recommend pasting the complete sidebar <div> in your answer with inline or separate `css` to help other SO users.

Comment: @abenci the css out of the page won't have the same result, here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/w4k50nbo/